# Acess Ubuntu server with static IP outside of the subnet mask

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu server that was previously configured to use static ip of the following: 192.168.2.XXX (in my case XXX=248).

And now I moved it to another router, and it still configured to work on this address so I can't access it from my local network. The new router subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, and it's working on 192.168.1.XXX.

I have accessed the server from the SSH and it's still on the old local address, but I don't have root access so I can't reset the network adapters.

How can I still connect to the server? Once I can connect to it from my machine then I can access the GUI and change the static IP to one within my range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your server is on the 192.168.1.x network but any time you send traffic to it that traffic is going to be routed to the gateway leading to 192.168.2.x. There is no easy way to resolve this. You may want to try adding a USB network card (which should get an address from DHCP, assuming you're running DHCP) and then fix the other NIC's address.

Comment: This server don'y have USB ports.. I think I'll find router where I can setup the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 so I access 192.168.2.XXX and that's it..

Comment: How will the traffic get back to you? This will only work if both boxes use that subnet mask. You may want to brush up on IP routing

Comment: I ended up using Cross Ethernet cable, and configured my PC to be on the same subnet as the server, and then I could access it and configure the IP.